# Javascript how to get position of selection in IFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe where the user can type anything they want. Lets say they have a long paragraph typed out and they highlight one word in it. They then click a button and this runs a javascript function. In my function I am able to get the highlighted word and store it but i cant get the starting and ending position of the selection. Here is my code so far:

```
<center><iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" ><?php echo $text;?></iframe></center>
<a class="buttonOnBar" id="btn14_quote" type="button" value="" onClick="javascript:iquote();" title="Quoteify"><img id="btnOnBarImg"src="img/icons/quote.png"></a>
function iquote(){

var len = document.getElementById("richTextField").contentWindow.getSelection().toString().length;

var start = document.getElementById("richTextField").contentWindow.document.selectionStart;
alert(start);
var end= document.getElementById("richTextField").contentWindow.document.selectionEnd;
var selectedText = document.getElementById("richTextField").contentDocument.getSelection();

}
```

neither selectionEnd or selectionStart give me the position in the iframe of the text. It just says undefined. What am I doing wrong?